# What are these Google Maps glowing spots?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, remote-sensing

Can any help me by identifying these glowing spots on the google maps image below? Am I in danger(I live nearby)?
[Google Maps Link](https://maps.google.gr/maps/ms?msid=205482134463162134306.0004d93fa4da933319d76&msa=0&ll=35.329663,25.125596&spn=0.001241,0.002642)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the science behind it, but I'm pretty sure it's just a particularly intense reflection of the sun off a shiny roof.  These used to show up on Google Maps in my hometown until the last imagery update.

I think you're safe!